# Closing SQL-connection but open connections keeps incrementing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following method:

```
public DataSet GetDataSet( string sp, params SqlParameter[] parameters ) {
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString
    ) ) {
    using ( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand() ) {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = sp;

        if ( parameters != null ) {
            foreach ( SqlParameter parm in parameters ) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add( parm );
            }
        }

        if ( conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed ) {
            conn.Open();
        }

        using ( SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter( cmd ) ) {
            da.Fill( ds );
        }
    }
}

return ds; }
```

I've noticed that multiple connections are created when calling this method multiple times (about 50 times).
I've checked this by executing this query in SQL:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) as 'DbNAme', COUNT(dbid) as 'Connections' from master.dbo.sysprocesses with (nolock) WHERE dbid > 0 GROUP BY dbid
```

The number of connections keeps incrementing when calling the above method. Shouldn't it use the same connection over and over again (connection pooling) instead of creating new ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) explains connection pooling very well. If you want to understand the whole thing you should read this one it is very good.

> Connection pooling reduces the number
> of times that new connections must be
> opened. The pooler maintains ownership
> of the physical connection. It manages
> connections by keeping alive a set of
> active connections for each given
> connection configuration. Whenever a
> user calls Open on a connection, the
> pooler looks for an available
> connection in the pool. If a pooled
> connection is available, it returns it
> to the caller instead of opening a new
> connection. When the application calls
> Close on the connection, the pooler
> returns it to the pooled set of active
> connections instead of closing it.
> Once the connection is returned to the
> pool, it is ready to be reused on the
> next Open call.

Answer (score 4):

try to increase maximum pool size in you connection string in web.config like this

```
<add name="ConString" connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=100;"/>
```

or wherever you defined it.it solves the problem but temporarily for permanent solution search your code probably you did not close the connection

hope it will help you

Comment: If I don't use the method above, the problem doesn't exist. At some point I have more than 100 connections open and then I receive the following error: _"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."_

Comment: @thomasvb you can also set the timout peiord in command more like following cmd.commandtimeout=100 or whatever time in miliseconds

Comment: @Devjosh I will try it but this isn't normal behaviour I guess?

Comment: @thomasvdb, yes that is for sure . but as i said are you closing the connection properly everywhere use try catch finally blocks and place connection.close() method in it that would be better. i pardon if suggested solution is loss making.

Comment: @Devjosh No need to apologize! Appreciate the effort!

Comment: Also check for datareaders/xmlreaders, make sure they are closed when exceptions occur

Answer (score 3):

Connection pooling doesn't mean that it will reuse the connection. Since it is expensive to establish a SQL connection the connection pool keeps a fixed maximum of connections opens, and when you call `.Close()` on the connection it is simply returned to the pool which then is able to pass it to a new connection when `Open()` is invoked on a new instance.

This mechanism is built into the SqlConnection class which is why it happens transparently to the user; in short: You shouldn't worry about the number of open connections as long as you are `using` the connections correctly (as you do).

Comment: At some point I get more then 100 connections which leads to this error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close connection after filling dataset. Using statment releases object but it doesnt close connection.

Comment: This is partially incorrect.  Using statement will call dispose on the connection and is equivalent to the Close method.  Whether the underlying connection is closed or not depends on pooling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2728ad(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: From MSDN: "If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. Close and Dispose  are functionally equivalent"