# Why doesn't the number of connections decrease after calling dispose on a connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run this code, the number of connections to my DB increases to 3 after `connection.Open()`. Why does it not go back down to 2 after `connection.Close()`?

```
private static void AdoNetStuff()
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Initial Catalog=abook;server=.\SqlExpress;Integrated Security=true");
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.Entity", connection);

    connection.Open();

    sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    sqlCommand.Dispose();
    connection.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
```

The above code is in a console app, and the number of connections doesn't drop back down to 2 until my console app closes.

This is how I'm checking the number of connections.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections, loginame as LoginName
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE dbid > 0 AND DB_NAME(dbid) = 'abook'
GROUP BY dbid, loginame
```

I can wait a while before ending the console app, and I still have 3 connections. As soon as I end the app, the number of connections drop back down to 2.

Comment: A side note: start using `using` for automatic disposal

Comment: @zerkms Thanks. I actually know that. I've inherited an app that uses the above scenario all over the place, without disposing anything. We're troubleshooting, and I'm trying to get a better understanding of what's happening in this particular situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043069/closing-sql-connection-but-open-connections-keeps-incrementing

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx "If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent. If the connection pooling value Pooling is set to true or yes, the underlying connection is returned back to the connection pool. On the other hand, if Pooling is set to false or no, the underlying connection to the server is closed."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL server uses connection pools for performance reasons. That means your connections will stay active even through you have called dispose.

Try calling:
SQLConnection.ClearAllPools();

To clear just the current connection try calling:

SqlConnection.ClearPool(ObjSqlConnection);

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.100).aspx: `When the application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it.` Okay, that makes sense as to why it remains open. But why do the number of connections drop after closing the app? Why doesn't that connection remain open, and in the pool, even after the app closes?

Comment: Connection pooling usually happens on a per-process (or per-AppDomain) basis. Systemwide connection pooling isn't really a thing.

Comment: I believe the pool is part of the db provider. That means its baked into the dll reference used by your application. Application closes, dll goes away along with the connections. I could be wrong about this however.

Comment: Maybe this excerpt, from my above link, has something to do with it: `If MinPoolSize is either not specified in the connection string or is specified as zero, the connections in the pool will be closed after a period of inactivity. However, if the specified MinPoolSize is greater than zero, the connection pool is not destroyed until the AppDomain is unloaded and the process ends.`

Comment: For clarity, are you wondering why the number is 2 rather than 0 or are you wondering why it drops after the app closes?

Comment: I'm wondering why it drops after the app closes. The app that I've inherited has almost 250 open connections. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Are there other connections being opened here besides the ones you show above? Perhaps they are going out of scope and not being closed until the GC finds them.

Comment: There are many connections being opened and not disposed, all over the app. I don't have it open now, but I think they are at least being closed.

Comment: Hmmm... well Im afraid I cant point you to a reason. However I would recommend as others have that you go back and wrap all of your connect and command calls in using blocks. I have apps that have thousands of calls in this fashion that run smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you are disposing before closing - `.Dispose` should be the last thing you do to a disposable object before you set the object variable to `Nothing`.

By disposing of a command and/or connection before closing it, you could be leaving the connection open.

Perhaps you could use a `Using` block for your `connection` and `sqlCommand`.

Comment: I tried calling `Close()` first but I still have the same issue. I'm aware of `using`. See my comment about that above. And thanks.

Comment: _By disposing of a command and/or connection before closing it, you could be leaving the connection open._ This statement isn't true, as far as connection objects are concerned. `Dispose` calls the `Close` method internally.